# How to configure SSL certificate in Docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, ssl, ssl-certificate, docker-container

How to configure an SSL certificate for ASP.NET Core in a Docker container?

I have a Visual Studio solution with multiple projects that I run on Docker Desktop; this is a "sandbox" environment for the purpose of evaluating code. This is not and never will be a "production" environment. So, the intent is to keep the configuration as simple as possible so I can focus on "real" work. (FWIW at some point I will need to redo this for production... but that is a different problem for another time).

The basic visual studio Docker container has a functioning SSL certificate: eg open `https://localhost:10433` in a web browser, the web browser reports the connection as secure with a valid certificate.

Running two docker containers

- service01 (hostname service01.local)
- service02 (hostname service02.local)

with container service02 accessing service01 over https.

The problem:

- accessing the https port on service01 from host using `https://localhost:10433` works.
- accessing the https port on service01 from host using `https://service01.local` raises certificate invalid warning (which you can override in browser)
- accessing the https port on service01 from service02 using `https://service01.local` fails... (see curl response below)

```
from host
> ping service01
pinging service01.local [172.26.13.76]
reply from 172.26.13.76 
etc

from service02
> ping service01
pinging service01.local [172.26.13.76]
reply from 172.26.13.76 
etc

from service02
> curl https://service01.local
curl: (60) schannel: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.
```

This all makes sense:

- https://localhost:port works as the certificate is trusted by Host.
- https://service01.local certificate is not trusted by browser because certificate CN=localhost not CN=service01.local
- service02 curl https://service01.local certificate is not trusted because service02 has not been told to trust it AND the CN is wrong

Basically, I need to get a new self signed certificate with CN=service01.local onto the service01 container.

I assume I need to do the following:

- on host, generate a new self-signed certificate with CN=service01.local
- on create service01 container, push this certificate into container (via Dockerfile or mount point)
- on service01 container, "load" certificate for ASP.Core application to use
- on service02 container, "trust" the certificate used on service01 container

As I noted: this is for a "sandbox" non-production environment, so something quick and dirty is fine (ie I want to avoid compose, kubernetics, reverse proxy, lets encrypt approaches; those tools just add another layer of complexity that I don't want to deal with right now).

Some of the relevant stackoverflow posts that I have reviewed so far

- [run docker service on https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50810165/run-docker-service-on-https) and
- [docker ssl certificate hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57310401/ssl-certificate-hostname-issue-in-case-of-microservices-internal-communication) and
- [c# ASP.NET Core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60724704/asp-net-core-application-in-docker-over-https)

UPDATE 1: one of the SO posts uses a powershell script to create and register a self-signed cert. Which looks great, except the base aspnet images dont include powershell from what I can tell. Installing powershell image over aspnet image is rabbit hole i dont need to go down.

UPDATE 2:
Using httpclienthandler to ignore ssl errors works for the httpclient, but didnt work for IdentityServer (token invalid error because authority must use https). Basically, Identity Server barfs if SSL / HTTPS connection is not valid. So really need a proper "certificate" for the container.

Reviewing the Microsoft doc on config https on docker, was not useful. basically confirmed that is how Visual Studio is configuring the dockerfile to run OOB. I have a valid dev-cert and it is being loaded to the container. I can confirm this by accessing the container with https://localhost:10433; the url is flagged as secure with the correct dev-cert. if I access the container with https://service01.local instead, the connection is NOT secure as "the certificate for this site is not valid".

A "single" docker container does handle https properly using the localhost port mapping (eg https://localhost:10433); it does not handle https property using the container hostname (eg https://service01.local). Using "multiple" docker containers is just an exasperates the problem.

UPDATE 3:
I gave up on the docker approach and went back to testing using https server (Kestrel). I switched all URL references to use the https://localhost:portnbr instead of https://containername. At which point all of the SSL functionality worked, as expected.

Basically, this means I cant use docker as part of the dev process, except for the most trivial of applications. But I have learned a lot more about the ins and outs of using docker.

UPDATE 4:
this error is off topic for this post, but... the question was asked.

Error communicating from secure web api (service02) to identity service (service01) is really, really weird. this is the code for the webapplication build.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("Bearer", options =>
    {
        options.ApiName = "myApi";

// FAIL: using container hostname
        //options.Authority = "https://service01.local";      
        
// FAIL: HTTPS service option
        //options.Authority = "https://localhost:52433";        

// PASS: HTTPS service with http access
// NOTE: if using http then must turn off require https
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:52080";           
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;                   
// NOTE: turn off require https metadata for testing only
    });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
```

- using docker with https://service.local FAILs as per previous.
- using docker with localhost:port FAILs > certificate invalid as container hostname is not included in certificate as Subject Alternative Name
- using https with https://localhost:52433 fails > connection actively refused by host
- using https with using http://localhost:52080 works > service 1 has `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` included in http request pipeline.\

now for the weird part. when I call `https://localhost:52443/.well-known/openid-configuration` from another app (service03) the https connection works. so why does setting the identity server Authority to https fail with "connection actively refused", yet using the same url from a web browser or a different service app or switching to http works?

I ran out of coffee trying to figure this one out. I really gave up, once I read the commercial licensing costs for the supported version Identity Server. Chalk this up as a good learning exercise.

UPDATE 5: creating self signed certs...
as per qiang-fu answer below, I need to create the appropriate certs.
here is the powershell script I am using to do so...

```
# Generate Certificate using OpenSSL
# Assume Git is installed, which includes OpenSSL client

write-host "STARTING GEN CERTIFICATE"

$outputFile = (Get-Item .).FullName
write-host "Working Directory: " $outputFile

# NOTE: single '' is used by powershell, versus "" used by OS
$openssl = 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\openssl.exe'
write-host "OpenSSL Executable: " $openssl

# UPDATE THIS: step options: 1-7, CA, SR, ALL
$step = 7

# UPDATE THIS: hostname to generate certificate for
$hostname = "service02"

# local variables
$caKey = "ca.key"
$caCert = "ca.crt"
$serverKey = "$hostname.key"
$serverCsr = "$hostname.csr"
$serverCert = "$hostname.crt"
$serverPfx = "$hostname.pfx"

# UPDATE THIS: certificate details
$certSubj = '"/C=CA/ST=BritishColumbia/L=Vancouver/O=MyCo/OU=MyCo/CN=MyCo.local"'
$certExt = '"subjectAltName=DNS:myco.local"'

$serverSubj = "/C=CA/ST=BritishColumbia/L=Vancouver/O=MyCo/OU=MyCo/CN=$hostname.local"
$serverExt = "subjectAltName=DNS:$hostname.local"

# show settings
if (($step -eq 0) -or ($step -eq "CA") -or ($step -eq "SR") -or ($step -eq "ALL"))
{
    write-host "Settings..."
    write-host "step $step"
    write-host $hostname
    write-host $caKey $caCert
    write-host $serverKey $serverCsr $serverCert
    write-host $serverExt
    
# TEST command will execute
    #& $openssl
    #& $openssl help
}

# Generate CA private key
if (($step -eq 1) -or ($step -eq "CA") -or ($step -eq "ALL"))
{
    & $openssl genrsa -out $caKey 4096
}

# Generate CA certificate
if (($step -eq 2) -or ($step -eq "CA") -or ($step -eq "ALL"))
{
    & $openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -days 365 -sha256 -key $caKey -out $caCert -subj "$certSubj" -addext "$certExt"
}

# Generate CSR for CA
if (($step -eq 3) -or ($step -eq "CA") -or ($step -eq "ALL"))
{
    #& $openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout $caprivatekey -out cert.csr -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -subj "$certSubj" -addext "$certExt"
}

# Generate Server Private Key
if (($step -eq 4) -or ($step -eq "SR") -or ($step -eq "ALL"))
{
    & $openssl genrsa -out $serverKey 4096
}

# Generate Server CSR
if (($step -eq 5) -or ($step -eq "SR") -or ($step -eq "ALL"))
{
    & $openssl req -new -key $serverKey -out $serverCsr -sha256 -subj "$serverSubj" -addext "$serverExt"
}

# Generate Server SSL Certificate along with certificates serial
if (($step -eq 6) -or ($step -eq "SR") -or ($step -eq "ALL"))
{
    & $openssl req -x509 -days 365 -sha256 -CA $caCert -CAkey $caKey -in $serverCsr -out $serverCert -addext $serverExt -copy_extensions copyall
}

# Generate Server PFX certificate
if (($step -eq 7) -or ($step -eq "SR") -or ($step -eq "ALL"))
{
    write-host "Generating PFX certificate: you will be prompted to enter a password and confirm it"
    & $openssl pkcs12 -export -in $serverCert -inkey $serverKey -out $serverPfx
    # -certfile root?
}
```

Running through this script I now have

- ca.crt, ca.key, ca.srl
- service01.key, service01.crt, service01.pfx
- service02.key, service02.crt, service02.pfx

the launchSettings.json for docker is now

```
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://+:443;http://+:80",
        "ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password": "password",
        "ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path": "/app/service01.pfx"
      },
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true,
      "httpPort": 52080,
      "sslPort": 52443,
      "commandLineArgs": "",
      "DockerfileRunArguments": "-h service01"

    }
```

At this point, service01 is running with the self signed certificate with the root CA included.

so now in web browser `https://service01.local` comes up with the correct self signed certificate. checking the certificate shows this is valid. same for all three service01.local, service02.loacl, service03.local.

UPDATE 6: still need a way to load the ca cert into the windows container as trusted CA. (lots of linux examples that work, but not windows examples). note that the container does not have powershell or certutil or openssl installed.

Comment: Why did you accept such a bad answer? Yes, you *do* need a valid certificate, especially if you want to use it for authentication. Even if you use Docker. Disabling validation means someone could put a proxy between your browser and server (like Fiddler) and intercept everything. The solution in development environments is to trust the development certificate, not disable validation

Comment: You don't need *powershell* to trust a dev certificate. The .NET SDK has [dotnet dev-certs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-dev-certs) for this. The docs at [Hosting ASP.NET Core images with Docker over HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-7.0) show how to trust the dev certificate *and* create an image that uses it too

Comment: 1 - I agree that disabling validation is "a bad thing" to do. But this was ok for my purpose (duplicating an example project to figure out how it functioned). Obviously not ok for a "real" application. (which is why I posted the question to SO.

Comment: 2 - dotnet dev-certs runs in the context of the Host; I have tried running in the context of the container... it should work there while the container is being spun up, but I ran out of coffee trying to figure that out. there is a SO example that uses powershell to generate, install, and trust a self-signed cert while spinning up the container. that didnt work for me because the base image doesnt include any version of powershell (looked through the entire file system to verify). Injecting powershell into the image just to generate a cert seems ass backwards.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Seen this problem days before. You could bypass the certificate validation by config the httpclienthandler when using httpclient in service02.

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>{return true;};
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient(httpClientHandler));
```

You can also add some validtion if you want

```
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => {
    if (cert.GetCertHashString() == "A7E2BA992F4F2BE220559B8A5371F05A00A6E750") //FingerPrint of the certificate
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

By the way, Below is my working command to run a dockerfile with certificate(.pfx)
`docker run -it -p 22007:22007 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+:22007" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=22007 -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="123" -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx -v ${HOME}/.aspnet/https:/https/ myimagename`
Reference [build container with https](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-7.0#running-pre-built-container-images-with-https)

----------------update of install cert----------
Steps of using openssl to create server certificate (pfx):
1.generate ca.key
2.generate ca.csr from ca.key
3.generate ca.crt from ca.csr + ca.key
4.generate server.key
5.generate server.csr from server.key
6.generate server.crt from server.csr + ca.crt + ca.key
7.generate server.pfx from server.crt + server.key

In step 6,you will be ask the Common Name(CN), you have to fill in the domain of server01 (or ip, depends on what API URL you are calling in service02).If not same the certificate will be invalid.

Then use the step7 pfx when run service01 docker to host https. 
My docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0   
COPY / /app/    
WORKDIR /app    
EXPOSE 22007/tcp   
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:22007
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/dockerBack.dll","--server.urls","http://*/22007"]
```

My working command (I put the server.pfx in linux home/username/app1/composetest folder):
`docker run -it -p 22007:22007 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+:22007" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=22007 -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="123" -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path="/composetest/server.pfx" -v /home/lighthouse/app1/composetest:/composetest imagename`

Then in service02, you could install the certifiate by adding "copy" "run" at begining in dockerfile. (I put the ca.crt in the same folder of docker file)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 
COPY ca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt
RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt && update-ca-certificates
COPY / /app/    
WORKDIR /app  
EXPOSE 22008/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:22008
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/docker-front.dll","--server.urls","http://*/22008"]
```

Then there will be no SSL error in my fetching https api test.(Needn't bypass validation)

Comment: LOL... if security gets in the way, turn it off!   Technically, changing the code is not what I was going for, but since this does achieve what I need, I will accept as an answer. (FWIW I do confirm that adding the validation callback does work).

Comment: I reviewed the command to run dockerfile with certificates; I dont actually need to do this. my visual studio config automagically handles this scenario (tested against the docker aspnetapp example). This works to enable https on a "single" docker container that is accessed from the Host. This does not work with "multiple" docker containers, where access is container to container. (see update 2)

Comment: the "turn off validation" worked until it didnt. the client handler approach made the http client happy with a bad ssl certificate, but Identity Server went "no, not a chance".

Comment: @lkujala are you using identity server container? what error message do you get

Comment: Interesting error: the Identity Server container is fine, it is the web api service that is validating a token that barfs. See Update 4 for details.

Comment: @lkujala I tested working sample with install cert to container using dockerfile, you could reference.

Comment: thx. testing this out. will provide an update when done.

Comment: see Update 5 for results of testing

Comment: generally everything works except for getting service02 to load the ca.crt as a trusted cert. the linux approach does not work in the windows context. looking through other SO posts for windows approach

Answer (score 1):

Disabling certificate validation is never an answer. For development/staging environments you can create and trust a self-signed certificate. The .NET SKD has the [dotnet dev-certs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-dev-certs) tool that allows creating and trusting development certificates.

The article [Hosting ASP.NET Core images with Docker over HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-7.0) shows how you can include and use your dev certificate inside Docker. The development certificate is mounted as a file on the container and the location and password are passed as environment variables.

You can create a new dev certificate with `dotnet dev-certs`, save it to a specific location  and protect it with a password. In the following command line, `<CREDENTIAL_PLACEHOLDER>` is the password

```
dotnet dev-certs https -ep %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p <CREDENTIAL_PLACEHOLDER>
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

After that, you can create your container using the new certificate and password

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/samples:aspnetapp

docker run --rm -it -p 8000:80 -p 8001:443 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=8001 -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="<CREDENTIAL_PLACEHOLDER>" -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx -v %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https:/https/ mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/samples:aspnetapp
```

The important parameters are :

```
-e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="<CREDENTIAL_PLACEHOLDER>" 
-e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx 
-v %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https:/https/
```

- `-e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="<CREDENTIAL_PLACEHOLDER>"`  passes the password to the container's `ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password` environment variable
- `-e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx` stores the inner location of the certificate in an environment variable
- `v %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https:/https/` mounts the folder where the certificate was created (`%USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https`) to the inner path `/https/`

Comment: Thank you for response. That is exactly what Qiang Fu recommended in his answer. This is also the OOB functionality when you enable docker in a project. As stated, for a "single" docker container that is accessed using a url like https://localhost:12345 the certificate created as per your answer works. However, once you use multiple containers (eg microservices setup), the certificate is not valid for container to container communication that uses the container hostname eg a url like https://service01:12345.

Comment: You can create certificates for those names too, just not with `dotnet dev-certs`. On Windows you can use [New-SelfSignedCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps) *on the host* and load it in the container

Comment: yes I did that. what happens then is the other container sees the certificate as "untrusted". So I need to somehow "trust" the certificate. In a web browser you can select "trust this certificate". I have no idea how you would do that from a service. somehow load and trust the certificate into the local store?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Docker Compose to build your apps on containers otherwise you will have to run long docker commands containing ssl codes in it.

In your docker-compose.yml file you can add ssl as:

```
version: '3.4'


services:
  multiapp:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}app1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app1/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9000:8080"
      - "9001:8081"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:8081;http://+:8080
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=8081
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=yourpass
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
        - ./app1/https/aspnetapp.pfx:/https/aspnetapp.pfx:ro
 
  multiapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}app2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app2/Dockerfile
```

Refer - [Multi-Container ASP.NET Core App with Docker Compose](https://www.yogihosting.com/docker-compose-aspnet-core/)

Comment: thx. I had looked at this a bit, but didnt work through it. I will give it a try.